# two army issue in TCP connection establishment

Tags: networking, tcp, transport

Is [two army problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem) seen in TCP connection establishment also?

I am sure it is for TCP connection release but iam not sure abt establishment.

If anybody could verify, it would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Should be moved to the Computer Science stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

It's not the same problem, mainly because when closing one of the segments should be ***the last segment***, so acknowledgements are not enough, you must use timers to decide if a stage has ended (you know those stages), so that you can decide that you must resend a `connection close request` of just close the connection because because it has passed too much time since the second `connection close request` is sent.

In the other side, when opening a connection there will not be a **last segment** because there will be following data segments, so just resending the lost connection stablishing segments will be ok: Once the opener gets the **acknowledge** with destination's sequence number, by his side the connection is already open. The origin then sends the third message of the **three-way handshare** just to confirm that it has got the destination's sequence number. Your doubt really is regarding what happens if some of this 2 segments are lost, but:

- if the 2nd message (acknowledge from destination to source) is lost it will just be re-sent
- if the 3rd message (acknowledge from source to destination) is lost it will just be re-sent

Hope it helps,

/Ángel